# How to close command windows with Java

Tags: java, window, command, runtime.exec

Each time I use `Runtime.exec("cmd /c start....")` I am opening a cmd window. I would like to create a more seamless application by closing each previous cmd window. How can I do this?

If anyone knows of a better way to run a series of commands in the same cmd window rather than opening new ones each time I execute a command, please let me know.

Comment: Why do the windows not shut? Are you starting long-running processes this way?

Comment: Yes. I'm opening a cmd window to run a script. And then I need to go to another directory that is inside my working directory and run another series of commands. This means that I have multiple cmd windows opening. I want to seamlessly run a series of commands one after the other in the same window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the opened windows from Java. But I suggest two solutions for you:

**First**:

```
Runtime.exec("cmd /c start /MIN ...")
```

The /MIN parameter will prevent windows from appearing.

**Second**: put all the applications you must call inside the same batch file and call it once. :-)

Comment: Minimizing the window doesn't really get rid of it.

Comment: The option of putting in a batch file might work better. I have tried the cmd /c with out start and my commands won't run. So I'll try the batch file route. Thanks everyone! I learned a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

Don't use start, that opens another window

Replace:

```
Runtime.exec("cmd /c start....")
```

with:

```
Runtime.exec("cmd /c ....")
```

Comment: You are so right. I didn't even notice that "start" in the command string, even when I was formatting it.

Comment: I didn't know what start did until now ;).

Comment: @Amara: in a cmd window, type START /? for help on that command.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need cmd windows?

I'd run the command directly in Java and capture the output and display it in a local window (if it's needed at all).

Just make sure you consume all the output from the program or it might stall.  Also remember to close the stdout, stderr, and stdin streams or some file handles might leak (well, that's true on some JDKs on some Unix OSes... Windows, who knows).

Comment: I'm trying to run python scripts and batch files. Is that possible to run directly in Java and how would I start? (I think I need to pose this as a question? :) )

Comment: @Amara: Python's script interpreter is a program, as is cmd.exe.  Both can be used with command-line arguments to execute their relative scripts (.py or .bat files).  Also there is Jython for executing python right in the VM, if you are interested.